# Google Tables INDIRECT function doesn't work how I want

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

For geting data from another sheet I use function **INDIRECT**

**=INDIRECT("s!$A1")**
but I foud a BUG: this formuls locate on another sheet, and if sheet, from which data will be received, doesn't exist yet, then the formula does not work, throws an error that it refers to an invalid range or sheet. If the sheet was created in advance with the desired name, then everything works correctly. If you create a sheet, and then rename it, then return the previous name again, it also does not work.

**s** - this is the title of the sheet

I found a temporary solution, it works as it should, but it also has a issue

**=IMPORTRANGE("link_to_this_file"; "s!$A1")** Here is the hard link to the file. This option is not suitable, because when copying a file, the formulas must remain working, otherwise everything will break.

Please let me know what can be done in this case. Maybe there is an option to read the file name to insert into **IMPORTRANGE** ?

Or is there some other function with similar properties besides **IMPORTRANGE, INDIRECT** ?

I found one more solution

**=query(s!A1;"select * limit 1")**
, but....
I don't understand how add the name of sheet dynamically
I need to read name from cell,(the name **s** located in F25 cell), if I change it to another (for example **g**)
the formula must changed to

**=query(g!A1;"select * limit 1")**

Answer (score 0):

Considering that INDIRECT works with strings, and you have in F25 the name of the street you could try:

```
=INDIRECT(F25&"!A1")
```

Or, if you have a name with more than one word:

```
=INDIRECT("'"&F25&"'!A1")
```

Comment: This I know, I did it. But as I told,... INDIRECT doesn't work, if sheet does'n exist. How can I use query function without INDIRECT because... i explained

Comment: Work only IMPORTRANGE and QUERY. But IMPORTRANGE linked to file, and QUERY doesn't read name of sheet from cell. If I insert INDIRECT into QUERY not work how me need, it if I use just INDIRECT.

Comment: fk... I made the experiment now. The function QUERY doesn't work normaly! I see one way - use the IMPORTRANGE, but i need parse the name of file from path https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/thith_path/edit#gid=1901460079      how? this_path extract from link

Comment: It sounds like overcomplicating something. It's understandable that any function won't work if the range doesn't exist yet. If you associate the name of the sheet in F25 to every formula that needs it with INDIRECT, just by updating the value of F25 all the formulas will recalculate. I think it's the easiest way

Comment: yep! i found, maybe      function GetSheetNameId() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
}

Comment: the first time this IMPORTRANGE function loads data for a long time. And it still works in a weird way. I don’t understand why if I rename the sheet, then return the desired name again - IMPORTRANGE cannot also get the data if I don’t update it in the cell or range it refers to. Is there really no way to view what I want in real time? Indeed, in fact: there is a sheet, there is data, but I can’t get them. How to bypass it? can somehow do Update formulas on the sheet, or something else. strange at all